# VSCoq Error: Connection to server got closed. Server will not be restarted

Tags: windows, visual-studio, coq, formal-methods, vscoq

I am using VSCoq with Ubuntu and WSL for a Formal Methods class I am taking this semester. I had it working fine (a trial in and of itself), but am all of a sudden receiving the following errors:

```
[Info  - 3:59:52 PM] Connection to server got closed. Server will restart.
[Error - 4:00:00 PM] Connection to server got closed. Server will not be restarted.
```

The first happens a few times, every 15 seconds or so, and then is followed by the second.

I have tried to delete the extension folder of VSCode (as explained [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/5163886/Fixing-VS-Code-Extension-Errors)) with disappointing results. I have also tried to reestablish the VSCoq language server within VSCoq. I tried to redownload it, but my system isn't having that either.

I'm using Windows 10 and Coq 18.8.0

Please let me know if you've ever run into anything like this.